Best loss function for predicting relative speed of two (or more) options
I want to create a model that tries to predict which execution engine will be faster for a given user query. The model does not have enough information to predict the actual run time, but we want to predict relative execution speed.
I think this means that the model should output an unbound positive number for each engine class.
The training labels are actual execution times for the query when using different engines.
I need a loss function that takes the model output (2 numbers) and actual times (2 numbers) and calculates loss.
What do you think is the most appropriate loss function here?
Some ideas:
For binary class label targets, the common loss function is CrossEntropy. But in our case, the targets are not binary.
We could normalize both model outputs and targets and then use CrossEntropy.
We could turn model outputs to a binary response. The loss for correct answer/order would be 0 while the loss for incorrect answer would be the run time difference.
For 2 class case, we could turn outputs and targets into ratios and calculate squared error.
We could consider output and target as vectors and calculate an angle between those vectors.
I like the concept of the BetaBinomial distribution (probability of the future binomial outcomes based on some prior outcomes). We can think of the model outputs as priors and calculate the probability of the target outcome. But BetaBinomial distribution is technically for integer quantities while our targets are real numbers. Would it still be correct to use the formula?

Among the options you mentioned you cannot find a 'best one' unless you first define what you want to model, e.g. mean relative speed or its full distribution? For example, if a model produces mean forecasts, then squared loss is a good loss function and absolute loss is a bad one. If the model predicts medians, it is the other way around. If you don't specify the statistic you're aiming at, 'best' makes no sense.
